# How do I approach a critical typo in someone else's otherwise very good answer?

Tags: discussion, editing

There is a complex question with a bounty ending tomorrow.  There have been a few partial answers posted, but everyone seems to be stuck in more or less the same place.  The answers are old enough that the answerers probably aren't coming back to check on the question very frequently.

But wait!

I was admiring the work of @feelinferrety in what is currently the [second most upvoted answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/55921/42184), when I saw that he had made a transcription error when copying information from the OP.  He had gotten stuck, but I believed he was on the right track, so I simply tried his last step again with the corrected information, and presto! I have found what I believe is the next clue.

Obviously I can't simply edit the answer.  Fixing the transcription error means they are no longer stuck.  I left a comment on the answer, but due to the nature of the question, these partial answers are very long, and much scrolling is required for anyone to see my comment.  I know that the answerer will be notified (I tagged him for good measure), but I am afraid he may not see it for a while.  I want the guy who did all the work to have a chance to keep going, but I also want to make sure that everyone else has the correct info so that they aren't spinning their wheels or giving up.

I don't feel like I can post my own answer because I didn't actually do any new work, and I haven't made further progress yet.  I would hate to steal credit from the person who actually figured out how to solve everything up to this point, just because they made an unfortunate typo.  I could keep trying and post when I have something new, but I'm not particularly good at this type of puzzle (though it's fun to try), and I want to make sure this new info comes to light.

What should I do in this case?

Comment: @SamHazelton Tagging the post owner doesn't do anything at special at all.

Comment: @boboquack Neither does misspelling a user's name when you tag them ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you've done is sufficient.  If the post author hasn't seen/acted on your comment yet, you might want to consider editing the post to correct the typo.

If your newfound knowledge enables you to make it further in the solution, then by all means post another answer.  Puzzlers work off of each other's work all the time around here.  If it was posted, the intention was that someone might be able to expand upon it.

If you haven't really made it any further in the solution and don't plan to, then I think pointing out the error and/or correcting it yourself is all that is required.  Others can go on from there if they're able.